# Vote to close unclear questions immediately after commenting?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, new-users

I'm a bit unsure what the correct procedure is when a question is unclear, but it looks as though the question can be fixed by OP. I.e., the question could be good if only OP knew how to ask questions.

I would of course comment and ask OP to elaborate and explain it in such a way that people understand it and may answer it. My question is: Should I vote to close as "Unclear what you're asking" at the same time?

The reason why I'm asking is: I guess (yes, this is a guess so I might be wrong) new users will lose hope and never fix the question if it's closed. They might not know there is a reopen function, and even if they do, they may doubt that their question will ever be reopened. Therefore by keeping it open we might get a new good question on the site, instead of another rubbish one that must be deleted after some time. On the other hand, there's no guarantee OP will fix the post if it's kept open, leaving a rubbish question open after all. I wouldn't vote down such a question without giving OP some time to fix it, but closing it is not really the same thing. However, if many new users will fix the question if and only if it's kept open, it might be worth it?

Any comments?

Comment: [Do you wait for edits before voting to close a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161877/165773) "...fast closure here serves the primary need to make reopening easier and protect the poorly worded good question from getting bad answers."

Comment: Yes, vote right away. It takes a while to get 4 other votes. The question won't be closed immediately unless you've got a diamond.

Comment: Related: [How soon should I "vote to close"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98022)

Comment: You should vote to close when the question meets our criteria for closing. Those criteria are there because they are indicators a question does not have what we need to be answered (or can't be answered because it's out of scope).  Closing also as a carrot and stick to help the OP clarify their question. Without it, they'd just comment and say, "Oh, that's nice" and not change anything.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Vote to close **right away.**

**In the aggregate, this benefits those who ask questions.**

The OP might not see it this way, but this is really true. When you take a look at what happens to unclear questions that have not been closed fast enough, what you see is a bunch of answers that don't actually answer that the OP meant to ask. So the OP gets a bunch of answers that have to be turned down, annoying the people who answered, etc.

The question can be reopened when it has been clarified, thus avoiding the unnecessary frustration of answers that miss a hidden target.

Comment: Thanks for this information, it looks like I was doing wrong by giving constructive comments rather than downvoting, and I will change my approach.

Comment: @MattCoubrough I'm not sure where you got the idea from this answer that constructive comments are somehow not desirable. By all means, if you want to leave a comment, then leave one. At the reputation you are at now, you can't vote to close but you can flag a question and select "it should be closed for another reason..." and then pick a reason there. The question will be sent to the close review queue. The point I'm making is that there's no good reason to *wait* before voting to close or flagging to close.

Comment: Sorry, that clarifies things thanks... I was getting confused over Vote to Close rather than Downvote. Sorry for the Noobish mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Downvoting (to hide them from the frontpage) and close-voting happens in order to prevent users from spending effort to answer an unanswerable question.

While the question is closed, it can still be improved, and OP is notified of that in the close message.