# How can we encourage close voters to use their powers?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I've noticed a recent trend for 3k+ users to comment and down-vote low quality questions, but not to issue a close vote.

Take this for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386686/sorting-fails-with-arraylist-with-custom-comparator

The question is missing crucial information - the definition of the piece of code that's failing. Five 3k+ people, myself included, added comments asking for this missing info. But at the time of writing, only one close vote is present (mine).

How can we encourage more 3k+ users to hit the close vote button? I'm strongly in favour of closing poor questions quickly, even if we re-open them ten minutes later. Assuming others feel this way, is there anything we can do to spread the interest in shooting down poor questions?

Comment: only one close vote but only 11 minutes old too (at the time of writing).  I dont disagree with the premise, this just isnt a good example

Comment: @Plutonix At the time of writing, at least 5 3k+ users had seen the question, because five had commented. I realise I missed that from my description! My question is how to engage these people to vote to close when they clearly dislike the question.

Comment: @Duncan, did you consider these users might have been out of close votes?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I hadn't no. I suppose I assume few people actually exhaust their votes.

Comment: It's surprisingly easy, actually.

Comment: I too dislike seeing a really bad question where people have taken the time to downvotes but not to VTC. But VIEWS as a metric includes all those without much rep at all, and perhaps anon views too(?)

Comment: @Plutonix I'm basing the trend on seeing 3k+ users interact with the question (i.e. commenting) but no close votes appearing. I'm not talking about the view count. As  Frédéric says, it may be due to lack of close votes, but I can't help doubting that causes much of this.

Comment: I've got 42 close votes remaining on SO, at the moment... I'm not a big close-voter, but I agree it's pretty difficult to run out of them...

Comment: I suppose we need a bigger sample of example questions to discount Fréd's suggestion.. but it's a huge stretch to assume that they've all used their close votes.. 1 person out of votes - sure - but still only maybe. 4 of the 4 people who interacted out of votes - a big stretch. the majority of 3k users we see doing this all the time out of votes.. c'mon, is this even a possibility worth discussing? - if that was the case then all our closing needs would be fulfilled already

Comment: No problem, I was just mentioning that because it happened to me before, and since the question is subtly blaming these users for failing to close I wanted to point out sometimes you *want to* but you *can't* :)

Comment: SE team may simply [hesitate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258263/does-the-broken-window-theory-apply-to-closing-questions/258373#comment36149_258373) to give such an encouragement. "Imagine there is a potential power out there, capable of closing 20x of all the questions that come in daily. Would you exercise some... _caution_ about unleashing it..."

Comment: I've seen 70K+ members answer blatantly duplicate questions instead of voting to close... if they're not going to use their close vote powers, then <shrug>.  The message I got from moderators was "People are free to answer, vote and close how they want."  Don't see how much can be done with that attitude.

Comment: I run out of close votes nearly every day, so I disagree that it's difficult to run out of them. (The plural of "anecdote" is "data", right?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387986/suggestions-for-learning-advanced-functional-website-design.  Comment from a 4K+ user, but my vote is the only close-vote, so he clearly didn't feel the need to close vote.  It's got five downvotes, so people feel strongly about the question, I just don't know if it's been flagged by low-rep users, or if people are just drive-by downvoting.

Comment: Reopening actually also doesn't work that well. We also need to encourage reopen voters to use their powers.

Comment: Personally... I prefer to tell a question-asker what is wrong with the question, and give them a few minutes to sort it out before I hit the close-hammer. Closing a question feels very final - especially to new users that don't realise it's ok, and just means "fix it and come back". I avoid the close-button til it's been up for at least long enough for the original author to respond to comments and have a chance to upgrade their question first.
I can no longer see the question, so I'm only describing my general policy.

Comment: there's enough abuse already by trigger-happy hordes of close-voters looking for the smallest possible reason to close questions within minutes. asking for a missing piece of information is a much more constructive way and i am heartened that only the horde is a small albeit insufferable minority. downvotes are a perfectly nice and a much better way to reduce the visibility of bad content, while leaving enough room to salvage it or allow excellent answers that may assume the missing information and create knowledge. down with book-burning!

Comment: @necromancer Maybe on quieter tags that works, but on something like [tag:java], which I frequent, the churn of new questions is endless. It's not feasible to manage requests for new information on countless questions concurrently. For me, if the info isn't there - comment and VTC. I don't want to waste any more time, just in case the OP never responds or updates their question. If they do, the system ought to cope with that (via reopening if necessary).

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Well said.  Even 100K+ and 200K+ users _prefer_ to answer FAQs even when there are one (or more) "related questions" (on the right) that answer the post.  It's like: _Give me the repz, please._  To sum it up, you can't "encourage" them to use their powers.  Unfortunately, there would be very few willing to shell out a dollar to "encourage" them by downvoting their answers on obvious FAQs.

Comment: They can just decrease the amounts of votes it takes to close. But the problem is, as many have said in the comments here, as well as the comments of other questions, the reopen queue isn't working as it should. If the reopen queue was working properly, you wouldn't be seeing such a split opinion about harsh closing.

Answer (score 30):

This problem reminds me of [the message to vote on questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/).

> You haven't voted on questions in a while, questions need votes too!

Perhaps we need one that tells you to vote-to-close if you vote down a lot of questions with no close votes despite the powers? It would need a link to [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) for those users who may not be aware what it means.

Yes, there are valid reasons to downvote without closing, but like with answer vs. question voting, it is *very* unlikely you read a lot of bad questions without some of those also deserving a close vote.

Comment: Excellent idea. This is what I'm looking for - practical ideas to engage the close voters.

Comment: *"You haven't downvoted in a while. Downvotes are important too!"*

Answer (score 4):

While I do occasionally recognize this trend developing I don't think it's something to be really concerned about...

Here's why:

A simple search query ( score -5 or lower and no answers - [see additional criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) )

```
is:question score:-100--5 closed:no created:2014-01..2014-06 answers:0
```

returns only **265** results.

On the other hand ( score -5 or lower and +1 answers )

```
is:question score:-100--5 closed:no created:2014-01..2014-06 answers:1
```

returns **1,587** results.

That's altogether only **1852** questions which need some close votes from the start of 2014 til now.

Reading between the lines? - why the hell did **1587** people answer instead of vote-to-close in first place? Yeah, saying this isn't going to encourage anyone to vote-to-close but I think this is kind of hitting the nail on the head showing that **people care for the reputation more than for the site and the rules itself**...

What we **can't** do it's establish some sort of connection between downvotes and voting to close. They need to be separated;

1. As someone has already pointed out - you may not see many votes as people may have already ran out (*and let's not argue but at least for me that's quite easy to achieve*)
2. Question may deserve a downvote (*for the reasons listed when you hover-over the downvote button*) but that same question may still be perfectly on-topic.

If the numbers of those grow and the trend is recognised by SE I would suggest:

- running a little one day(*one week*) campaign voting-to-close all those which deserve it with some extra **badges and/or hats** for participating.

Comment: Some kind of "It's ok to vote to close" event could be quite good. With a hat per day :-)

Comment: [WINTER OF HATE!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi haha yes please! but *sneakily* reword it!

Comment: [Winter of Discontent](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_III_(play))?

Comment: Winter is coming.

Comment: I'm not concerned about questions getting closed eventually. But to see a real quality boost in SO I think we need *swift* closure. And that will only come about with increased engagement with more close voters.

Answer (score 3):

Many users might not even know they have the privilege to do so. When you hit a mile stone in your rep, I believe you only get some kind of message saying that you now have the privilege to do "x". No education or detailed information is given. You are always handed the privilege before you actually know how to use it.

It is also likely that many users are here only to discuss technical things, not to do non-paid moderator work. There is no obligation to do any such thing just because you have the rep for it.

Anyway, the root of the problem is the flood of crap questions posted. If you constantly let herds of cattle walk through your living room, you might get concerned when you notice that they make a lot of noise, take a lot of space, break everything and poop everywhere. The solution for getting a clean living room isn't to recruit more people with brooms, but to keep the cattle out in the first place. Why would you want cattle in your living room anyhow?

Comment: [you dont just get some kind of message saying that you now have the privilege to do "x"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: @mehow My point is, you found that manually, by browsing the site. If the system was implemented as "Ding! You got x rep. Read this, then you get the privilege", the people interested in it would actually bother reading, while those not interested don't even need to be handed the privilege.

Comment: but what you have described is exactly how the site works. You gain privileges you get a notification - you click it and it redirects you to the correct /privileges page

Comment: @mehow And if you don't?

Comment: but you can't be forced - voting to close is voluntary. If you're willing to participate you click, you're not willing then that's completely fine...I don't thinking throwing this in peoples faces will bring us any good. I doubt we want to allow robo-vote-to-close types to start participating...

Comment: @Lundin I disagree with your response. I think many users know exactly what privileges are coming next - that's half the game at first. "Woooh I've got close powers!" etc. I also disagree with your premise that the flood of bad input is the problem. I'd argue that's an unavoidable issue; one that is best tackled through *swift* closure to encourage fewer people to answer such questions. Hence my question here - how to engage more close voters.

Comment: @Duncan The flood of crap is not unavoidable. Instead of having reviews on edits, intricate close & delete systems etc, we could as well have a mandatory review of the very first post someone writes, implemented in such a manner that their crap don't hit the site before passing review. If we need to engage 5 people to remove the crap, we might as well engage 5 people to review it in advance. I'm sure there are other ways as well.

Comment: @Lundin I completely agree. I thought we were discussing the system as-is. There is certainly room for new features like the ones you describe that might mitigate a lot of the crap.

Comment: @Duncan We are discussing the system as-is, which is broken, because for every imbecile posting a crap post, the system needs 5 users of good standing (3k rep) to deal with it. And also likely some additional work caused by an edit of the crap, which in turn involves 1 helpful user doing the edit and 5 more users of good standing doing edit review. So to fix the mess caused by 1 ignorant imbecile, the site likely involves 11 users of good standing. And then people wonder why there aren't enough close votes. Likely the imbecile per trusted user ratio is far too high, ensured by the site design.

Comment: So another feasible solution is probably to reduce the number of close votes needed.

Answer (score 3):

I frequently find questions which to me seem within the rules, but where I'd still like additional clarification, so I'm one of those people that comments on questions without voting to close them.  I know full well I can vote to close; I just don't think the question should be closed.  That's probably true for most of those other people who do that, too.

The idea that one could count on a question being closed and then reopened 10 minutes later when the information was added is laughably unrealistic.  Reopening a question once closed is very difficult.

Comment: "*Reopening a question once closed is very difficult.*" I disagree. The [reopen review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) is always nearly empty. It's far easier to have a question reopened (once voted upon) then it is to close it in the first place. Also, posting a link to a question worthy of reopening to Meta tends to get it reopened pretty quickly.

Comment: @Cupcake the reopen review queue normally results in questions remaining closed rather than being reopened, even when they have been extensively edited to add information.  It's easy to get a closed question reviewed for reopening, but actual reopening of the question remains very difficult.

Comment: @WarrenDew It would be interesting to see if there is data to back up your claim (that questions in the reopen queue typically remain closed). Or examples of questions that should have been reopened that weren't.

Comment: "Reopening a question once closed is very difficult." – If that is true, it's a separate problem. A lot of questions already get closed, just (often) slowly.

Comment: @otus They get closed slowly because people are hesitant to close. The reason for that? Because they know the reopening of that question is nearly impossible, even though the question deserves to be opened again.

Answer (score -3):

I think there is a reasonable herd effect in the forums. If someone downvotes, or votes to close a question, then others often follow quite quickly.

I don't think we should be pushing people to close votes any faster. Last week, I selected to close [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206997/how-to-draw-a-qpixmap-with-rounded-corners) due to the OP answering his own question. Having been a little uncertain as to whether or not this had been the right thing to do, I consulted meta, which clarified, in my mind, that I was a little too hasty.

Before I had returned to the question, to relinquish my close vote, others had quickly started to follow my lead in berating the OP and he'd also received a downvote. I expect there may have been more had I not removed my vote to close and posted the meta link explaining my actions.

I expect the inaction of my voting to close would have been better here for the question and its visibility.

While this is an isolated incident, to me it highlights that we shouldn't be pushing people to close any quicker, but rather to consider the true value of the question with regards to being a SO resource. Even if a question is re-opened, I feel there is an effect to how it is received by the community.

The difficulty here, is, of-course, that the need to close a question is not always black and white. I'm sure we could all find a questions that we agree to close and ones where we'd differ in opinion. In the cases of the obvious poor questions, it would be great to have them closed quickly, but how do we differentiate those from the questionable ones?!

Comment: Conversely, countless regular SO users are complaining about the drivel on the front page. The goal is to close these down fast and clear the way for great questions. I'm not wanting to encourage people to close for the hell of it, but if they've got as far as saying "*Cannot reproduce this - we need more code. Post method XYZ*" as a comment, then they should be voting to close accordingly. We cannot assume the OP will ever bother to edit their question again.

Comment: Not that I disagree with you, but do regular users spend much time on the front page? Personally, I just use tags that I'm interested in (those in which my skills reside) and filter on those.

Comment: I say "front page", but really I mean "whatever list of questions you like to look at". The goal is to close and remove as many bad questions as possible from the site, thus impacting positively any view you use to access questions.

Comment: Ah, I see. I do agree with you, to some extent. It's just difficult sometimes to determine when one question is 'bad' as not everyone will agree. I believe this is the benefit of having to vote to close, rather than the power being assigned outright. I do, however, think that closing prematurely and re-opening a question has a negative impact upon it for both the question and the OP.

Comment: @Duncan, swift closure is one thing, but it still clutters the lists (in order of activity) since questions that are on hold or closed are still visible until deleted (and deletion definitely doesn't give a chance for improvement). Perhaps we'd need a filter in those views for those in a hurry to hide questions that are on hold or closed unless they have been edited since these votes.

Answer (score -17):

> I'm strongly in favour of closing poor questions quickly, even if we re-open them ten minutes later.

I'm not. <strike>One of the problems with close votes is that you can't revert them.</strike> You're not giving much opportunity for the asker to improve the question.

- For some reason (unfortunately without statistical evidence to back this up), I get the impression that votes attract other votes (that might not be just for close votes, by the way).

  If I'm reading a question quickly, without having much time to spend on it, I'll probably be more tempted to use my close vote if I see another close vote has already been cast. It will just catch my attention a bit more, thinking "oh, that must be a low quality question". In this case, I'll just have a very quick read without giving the question a real chance.

  I've become aware of this with experience, but it was more tempting when I first got these voting powers.
- "*[...] if we re-open them ten minutes later.*". This is certainly a good reason not to vote for closure in fact. While saying that "we" will re-open them ten minutes later sounds like it could work, that's just wishful thinking in practice. Gathering the required votes within those ten minutes just never happens.

  Sometimes, you have to wait for days for a question to be re-opened. There are a few questions where I've asked for clarifications in comments, got those clarifications a few hours later (the question was editing into a reasonable question), but by that time, the question had been closed. Even though I had an answer for such questions, I simply couldn't write it there and then. Votes to re-open tend not to attract other re-open votes in the same way, possibly because people don't revisit the question (unless the title has changed completely).

  Of course, in this case, it's always possible to leave a comment to tell the asker to re-ask as a new question, but I'm not sure it's a good idea. (It can cause problems if someone has already had a go at providing an answer, in which case the asker can't delete it straight away, which makes the whole problem even worse).
- I find that the new gold-badge duplicate closing power has actually made me more cautious about casting a close vote. Before, it was leaving a comment saying "Possible duplicate of ...", leaving a change for the OP to edit and clarify why it isn't. (I know duplicates are not always very welcome on SO, but apart from very basic questions, there are often slight details or a different context that make the question sufficiently different, although very similar to another one.)

If we want to give askers (in particular new users) the opportunity to improve and contribute to SO, I don't think closing too fast is going to help much. There's very little incentive to improve your question once it's closed, and bad askers will keep asking bad new questions.

---

**EDIT:**

Here is an example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24434977/372643) probably wasn't a recommendation question at its core, but was worded similarly to one. I've edited it to word it a bit better, and voted to re-open, only to realised that the OP had [re-asked it as new anyway a few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24449351/372643).

Was it worth closing it in the first place so quickly? Probably not. Askers may be in different timezones than those who vote to close (or busy with other things). In the end, that question was improved within a day (and the initial question still hasn't been re-opened).

Comment: "One of the problems with close votes is that you can't revert them." – Yes you can? Click on the close (n) link and "retract". Or do you mean after the question is closed? That's what reopen is for.

Comment: I disagree entirely. I'm fed up of rubbish questions and I want them closed fast. Too often, OPs post a useless question, but still get a flurry of answers, one of which just suffices. They never clean their question up or respond to the comments asking for clarity underneath. Only closure tells them they *must* fix their question. And note: the question is *On Hold*, which tells them there is hope yet!

Comment: @otus, good point, I had missed that recent feature... Nevertheless, the re-opening barrier is still an issue.

Comment: @Duncan,  I guess it depends on the question and possibly which tags you visit. What you're saying is clearly a problem for beginner questions that are incredibly vague. There are however a number of questions that lack details because the error message is quite obscure (for example) and the OP can't necessarily write down the entire context. It's hard to tell these two categories of questions apart, that's the main problem.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256331/839601

Comment: @gnat, I don't necessarily disagree, and I do vote to close quite regularly, but when I have a doubt and I feel that the question could be improved with additional details, I don't vote to close. As I said, voting to re-open always seems to take ages in practice (if it ever happens). Maybe I've just been on SO for too long and I've learn the dark art of ignoring questions I don't want to see...

Comment: _"You're not giving much opportunity for the asker to improve the question."_ Isn't the whole point of closing a question to give the OP a chance to improve the question before (more) poor answers are added to it?

Comment: @Duncan If an answer is posted that "suffices", even if only "just", then by definition the question contained enough information to put together a useful answer, and anyone asking for clarification should not have been voting to close on that basis.

Comment: @WarrenDew Not true in a number of cases. Plenty of off-topic questions can be answered but should be closed.

Comment: @unit3524344, not really, sometimes questions aren't greatly worded, but can have a reasonable answer. (I'm talking about on-topic question.) The very fact that answers to such questions can be produced and accepted just shows that at least someone understands them. I've just added an example.

Answer (score -28):

I am a 92k user and I basically consider the whole close system harmful. Preventing would-be-helpful people from giving an answer to a question just because you think the question is invalid or unanswerable is antisocial behavior and I wish the people doing it would go spend their efforts on Wikipedia or some other community where policing bad content at least has *some level* of positive value.

Comment: SO is like Wikipedia in that we're building a reference for future readers; policing bad content has similar value here.

Comment: That attitude is the whole problem. Of course even if you accept that it's valid, closing still has no value. Bad questions do not detract from the value of good questions and answers. Bad/wrong answers do detract, but downvoting them (or in extreme cases where they're already accepted and widely upvoted, but blatantly wrong, editing in an editorial note to that effect) works fine.

Comment: @R.. By closing bad questions, we encourage helpful people to focus on questions that benefit more people in the future. So there *is* a benefit across the site.

Comment: Also, another reason for closing is that the flood of bad questions cause good users to leave the site, because nobody wants to swim in a flood of crap.

Comment: Ship happens.  So lets promote it.  Huh.

Comment: @Duncan: No, you encourage people to waste their time on meta arguing about why closing is bad rather than answering questions and being helpful.

Comment: @devnull I don't understand your last comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: As a 5k rep user, I see the close vote system helpful. I don't participate much on meta, but I read the community bulletin posts. When I see a question that's clearly off-topic, I downvote, submit a close vote, and move on. By clearly defining what I should and should not be answering, I feel less obligated to waste time on poor-quality questions. Is this a perfect reason? No, but mentality plays into the system, and telling people what they can and cannot asks forces people to ask better-quality, on-topic questions as a result. No consequence would make bad questions more common.

Comment: @JakeKing: If you feel the question is low-quality, by all means downvote and don't waste your time answering it. But preventing others from answering it is not a contribution.

Comment: @R. "Preventing others from answering it is not a contribution." Yes, it *is.* Do you really want people answering low quality questions? No? *Closing prevents them from being answered*. And if someone sees a low quality question that's open, *they might ask one too!* So by closing low quality questions, you prevent crap from being in the system and discourage future crap (as it'll be deleted soon enough).

Comment: Why should I care if somebody answers a low quality question? If the answer is that they'll get rep for doing something that's not contributing to the community and thereby undermine the rep system, then make it so closing doesn't prevent answering but just prevents getting positive rep for answers on the closed question (and still allows getting negative rep from downvotes).

Comment: Yahoooooooooooo!