# Disable deletion of your own question if it has any answer at all, even if downvoted

Tags: feature-request

Scenario:

1. I, and others, wast..spend time commenting hints to a user whom we don't immediatey identify as a homework vamp.
2. Some rep-PSW post a complete coded, tested, working answer.
3. Annoyed by the rep-PSW, I downvote the answer to the bad question, so it's at -1.
4. The OP immediately deletes the question to hide it from his/her prof.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664188/return-a-counter-out-of-a-loop-c

This is exceedingly annoying behaviour, and posters should not be able to delete their own question under those circumstances (OK, maybe with 500 rep, say).

Comment: What benefit is there in keeping the question around? Particularly so if you're already seemingly annoyed with the question and the OP, if I go off of some of your comments.

Comment: I believe this has been requested before (on main meta and here)...

Comment: did you [vote to close after commenting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256328/839601)?

Comment: @JonClements [Disallow deletion of questions for 24 hours after last answer was posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207810/165773)

Comment: @Bart  the question was not so bad that it justified closure, not at first, anyway.  It had code, it had a valid answer.  I've seen worse, (frequently).

Comment: Given that the OP will pop up on the admins' or the system's radar if they do this persistently (I think), a strong argument can be made that everything went fine here: the answerer learned not to answer garbage questions, and  the garbage question is gone. If you witness this kind of behaviour, a mod flag may make sense, too

Comment: @Pekka웃 yup....

Comment: OH.. a dup:((  I did search, but obviously not well enough.  Oh well, I deserve my downvotes, then;)

Comment: @Pekka웃 most such posters are on one account per question anyway:(

Comment: @MartinJames that dup doesn't count since it's on other meta (MSE)

Comment: Meh, some vampires are going to score a question to their crappy question - that's expected, and it's no big deal. The answerer, however, learns a valuable lesson from the deletion, and the more do that, the lower the likelihood of the vampire being successful

Comment: I tend to be rather unsympathetic towards users that receive an answer (and just because the community hasn't had time to upvote it) pretty much immediately delete their question and in doing so waste someone else's time. That's not playing fair or being nice. Of course - if it's a bad question and a bad answer - then it's really the answerers fault for wasting their time on it - so we all just have to shrug that case off.

Comment: If we're aware of a genuine case of a "hit'n'run" - we'll pretty much always undelete the question and leave it for a bit to see what the community thinks. If necessary we can lock the post or even suspend the new user while we reach out to them to prevent them deleting it again and let the "natural" voting/closure etc... from the community take place.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281399/2675154

Comment: And as Tim Post mentions in the linked MSE post - we can always request disassocation (and sometimes work with the user to anonymise bits if needs be) so we can keep everyone's efforts about. We only get flags such as: (paraphrasing) "I didn't realise my post was public   and I got the answer I wanted but I'll fail my exam if my professor finds out... I can't delete it"... A few cycles of repeated flagging begging deletion, then sometimes we get the "IF YOU DON'T DELETE MY POST I'M GOING TO STICK MY LAWYERS ON YOU MF!". Oh what fun... :p

Comment: @MartinJames: "*Annoyed by the rep-PSW, I downvote the answer to the bad question, so it's at -1.*" Was the answer a bad answer? If not, then you had no right to downvote it.

Comment: @NicolBolas the way Martin describes it, answer was spoon-feeding, these seem to be generally considered not okay (teach to fish vs give fish)

Comment: @gnat: ...so? The downvote icon says "this answer is not useful," not "this answer does not teach you how to solve the problem yourself." An answer is still an answer even if it's a short text blurb and a pile of copy/pastable code. It's not necessarily a good answer, but it's not an *incorrect* one either. Correctness, completeness, and so forth a reasons to downvote. Not because you believe the answer is from a "rep-PSW" or whatever.

Comment: @NicolBolas I haven't read bigger bulls#it here yet. Are you of those rep whores? I told you that some consider "give-fish" spoonfeeding not useful, that gives them 200% right to vote down, totally according with tooltip

Comment: @NicolBolas answer shown in example post deserves -10 for using `while` loop to get remainder of division. In most cases I've seen such "answers" are not suitable for SO. Additionally in most cases only explanation is "try this" - again deserve downvote.

Answer (score 9):

I deleted the question because the feedback on it was so extremely negative.  I figured that the question was so bad that it was not worth anyone's time at all...so I put it out of it's misery and embarrassment.

I learned my lesson about when to ask questions and figured my problem out on my own.

Apparently I've taken some massive mis-steps as far as SO etiquette goes and I apologize for causing such a stir. I am not going to delete my account.

Interestingly though, I got a 'peer pressure' badge for deleting a question that had a score of -3 or worse.  So from that moment until about two minutes ago, I thought I'd done the right thing.

Comment: No worries. Ideally, take the feedback (about debugging and such) to heart and forget the negativity - SO is a big place and forgets everything over time. :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thank you for your response.  I will improve.