# Questions that can only be asked "why isn't this working?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

For reference - [Sorting input radio boxes alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890088/sorting-input-radio-boxes-alphabetically/36891877)

The above question has been severely down-voted, and has two votes to close, because it asks "why isn't this working". In this scenario, the OP has attempted to code his sort and it simply isn't working for him. How else can he ask this question so that it doesn't get such harsh reception.

How should these questions be handled? I don't see how else the OP could've asked this question.

Comment: Did you see the edit history of that question?

Comment: Because I guess that is not A Complete, Verified and Minimal Example. This guy wrote a function, it's not working, and asks for debug...

Comment: It's absolutely mandatory to describe how it isn't working.  Even knowing that code fails to return values is better than "it doesn't work."

Comment: This kind of question is just annoying.  Still, there is worse - those who ask 'why does it do this' with some output but, after 20 comments and suchlike timewasting, we find out that the OP has not even bothered to try it and had just typed in the source from their homework and posted it off to SO.  Moral - even if the poster says how it's working or not working, they may be be being economical with the truth or downright liars.

Comment: @TheLostMind I saw the initial question. His only problem out-of-the-gate was that he couldn't get his JSFiddle posted in the question correctly. Assuming this is his first question with a fiddle, he may have struggled getting it included. I later edited the question to include it as a snippet, but the code was all there in the fiddle.

Comment: @Tricky12 - Agreed. Things like that often lead to DVs and CVs. People tend to jump to conclusions on what they see right now instead of waiting.

Comment: Agreed - as edited, the question is reasonable (though possibly a duplicate). Your answer requires changing the HTML in the question, where that's not strictly necessary, so I'd say the downvote is defensible. *I'd suggest not asking "why the downvote?" on meta unless you are trying to round out your downvote collection.*

Comment: "it is not sorting all items as it should be." - Its not clear as to what it "should be" sorted as. hence meeting the downvote requirements

Comment: @PaulRoub I simply added that piece to emphasize the question. I've seen several times that good answers get down-voted because the question is bad and it's considered spoon-feeding. I couldn't care less about votes, I just like helping people out, even if it's just with how they ask their questions. I just find that in some scenarios questions almost have to be asked "why isn't this working?" because they become dumbfounded with what else to try.

Comment: @Sayse In the question title it does mention alphabetically. I suppose that's easy to look past when reading the actual question, though.

Comment: @TheLostMind Of course, the user could just *not post* until his question is ready, saving him the downvotes and answerers the time of reading crap... Also, I don't see the inability to post jsfiddle links as a reasonable reason; **post the code in the question** and use jsfiddle for backup.

Comment: *His only problem out-of-the-gate was that he couldn't get his JSFiddle posted in the question correctly.* Their problem was trying to cheat the requirement that the post contain code when linking to JSFiddle. That's why there's a comment talking about *"circumventing the message about including the code as well as the link"* and why the edit history shows the OP trying to format the JSFiddle link as code. This isn't a case of the OP being confused about how the site works; the site told him to include code.

Comment: I feel @Tricky12 view is right. We should help newbie users post answers rather than just down-voting and closing them.

Comment: @AniMenon 8 THOUSAND new questions each day on stack. Most of them newbie users. Only a handful of people to show/educate those new users. Not scalable. Have fun doing it. The sad fact of this is you'll burn yourself out.

Comment: @Patrice I am just saying try to do it, rather than just get them all closed.

Comment: @animenon if they stay open,the quality of the site goes down. You seem to not know the intent and purpose of Stack. Quality of Qs and As has ALWAYS been priority 1. To keep that up, prompt closure is needed

Comment: @Patrice alright.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How else can he ask this question so that it doesn't get such harsh reception.

He can explain *specifically* what happens when his code runs, what *should* happen, and (if necessary) how the two are different from each other.  If there is an error then it should provide that error, if the output is incorrect it should both explain what is incorrect about the output, along with an example that includes the input, actual output, and desired output, along with a description of what he's done so far to diagnose the problem, describing what he has done to diagnose the problem, how he's narrowed down the issue into the portion of the code that is/isn't working, etc.

> How should these questions be handled?

Some combination of the following:

- Downvote the question
- Vote to close the question
- Comment on the question to explain how it can be improved

Comment: All of this is great, and I appreciate the useful answer. However, should we avoid answering these types of questions until they have asked them in a more proper fashion?

Comment: @Tricky12 Yes, as the answer states.  Notice how there is no bullet for "ignore all of the missing information and try to answer the question anyway" when describing how to handle such questions.

Comment: Fair enough. It's just difficult sometimes to differentiate between someone struggling to post their question legitimately and someone trying to play the website for homework solutions. When I feel the person is honestly trying to ask their question, but struggling, I do try to answer it if I can. I'll start pushing more towards bettering the questions. Thanks again for the post!

Comment: @Tricky12 see [Vote to close unclear questions immediately after commenting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256328/839601)

Comment: @gnat I understand the reasoning in that question and its answers. In the question I mentioned, though, I had no issue understanding the question. The problem was that the code was in the JSFiddle and not the question itself. The 30 seconds it took to open his JSFiddle by URL was enough for me to understand the question. A simple edit, in my opinion, fixed the question. I completely agree with you when the question is completely unclear.

Comment: @Tricky12 if you have that much free time - indeed you can *instead* edit question in shape yourself (preferable cooperating with OP). Note that in 99% of cases editing such questions in shape (like providing good MCVE inline) would make question blatantly obvious.