# Users who get flagged for insulting/abusive comments should not be able to flag for closing/holding the same question

Tags: feature-request, flags

My original question

[Why is my ItemsControl not render ILookup<T,V> when set as ItemsSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703721/why-is-my-itemscontrol-not-rendering-its-contents)

received a comment from a user @clemens inferring that I could not be bothered to fix my question because my response was slow. It was the end of the work day and I intended to pick it up the next day.

I flagged the comment as abusive and then @clemens went through my profile and started posting notes about spelling mistakes he found there on the original post about XAML data binding. I flagged those as abusive/offtopic as well. These comments were deleted but the user then flagged my question for closing which then triggered a cascade of downvotes.

I had originally answered his snarky comments but after realizing I was being trolled I deleted my responses.

I've since answered my own question and rewritten the original question, which is easy in hindsight to make clearer but the close flag will probably stick.

My suggestion is that users who get flagged for abusive/insulting comments should not be allowed to flag for deletion/holding the question they got flagged on.

Comment: It would make for a fun new move to game the system: flag all dissenting comments to preempt down/closevotes… Uhm, yeah… no thank you.

Comment: My error. Was not a downvote but a flag to "Put on hold" I used the wrong terminology. Sorry

Comment: You might want to read this [MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289909/should-any-meta-post-that-calls-out-a-user-by-name-be-deleted-not-just-downvote) and see if you want to address that aspect of your question.

Comment: _"but after realizing I was being trolled I deleted my responses."_ <-- there's your problem. You weren't being trolled. Just because someone has a different opinion, doesn't make them a troll. Those comments weren't offensive at all. Maybe a little blunt, but bluntness isn't illegal.

Comment: @Cerbrus The user claimed that I could "not be bothered" to fix my answer. How he came to that conclusion was unclear. I was offline and sleeping. When I called him on it the next day he went through my profile and started posting spelling mistakes he found there. This is not a different opinion but trolling.

Comment: Note, the moment someone starts calling other users "Trolls", I find it difficult to take their meta question seriously. If you _are_ looking for help for a _real_ issue, refrain from namecalling like that.

Comment: @Cerbrus You seem to take it seriously enough to post a comment :)

Comment: Where are those "typo" comments?

Comment: [Vote to close unclear questions immediately after commenting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256328/vote-to-close-unclear-questions-immediately-after-commenting), http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close

Comment: Looking through that train wreck of a comment thread… Just walk away in such situations. Do not engage. Flag if necessary. You're not improving the tone and mood of the site if you fire back.

Comment: @deceze I agree. I deleted my responses to the comments. I should not have originally responded.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Someone telling you that they can't be bothered to fix your post for you isn't offensive.  At worst, it's simply irrelevant (I don't need you to tell me that you can't be bothered to edit my post, just don't edit my post in silence).  It's nowhere *near* an offensive comment.  The user going through your post pointing out mistakes/errors is posting *helpful* comments; that *certainly* isn't offensive.  You insulting them for spending time helping improve your posts on the other hand is *very* rude.

Comment: @Servy   He told me that I couldn't be bothered to fix my post not that he could be bothered to fix mine. I had given no reason for him to believe this other than not answer fast enough.

Comment: He didn't go through my __post__ for spelling mistakes he went through my __profile__. That was totally off topic.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Considering you've since specifically said that you couldn't be bothered to fix your post, they were apparently correct.  It sounds like you're upset because they were right, not because they said something offensive.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Going through various posts you've made and pointing out errors in those posts is *not* off topic.  If they were mentioning errors *not in those posts* then sure, that'd be off topic, but that's not what you said.

Comment: @Servy I never said that. Sorry if you have misunderstood anything I have posted. I will clarify if you need.

Comment: @Servy He used the comment thread about __XAML__ data binding to point out spelling mistakes in my employers name on my profile. These are not related topics.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing That's not actually what you said, but while that *is* being helpful and pointing out an error that you'd made, you are correct that *that* would be off topic, although not otherwise inappropriate.

Comment: @servy I'm sorry you misunderstood. I've edited the text to show he was cross posting and offtopic.

Comment: @deceze You seem to have access to the transcript of the thread. User Servy is claiming I was rude to clemens but I can't get the original transcript as it is all deleted. Is it against S.O policy to share the original if you have access. I can't retrieve it.

Comment: Just [let it go, let it goooo~.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0MK7qz13bU) The conversation went off the rails, period. There's no point in pointing fingers after the fact. You both weren't at your best. Don't repeat the same thing here, everybody.

Comment: ok ok Voice of reason prevails :) I'm out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My suggestion is that users who get flagged for abusive/insulting comments should not be allowed to down vote the question they got flagged on.

Why?

Just because they didn't know how to behave doesn't mean their downvote (if it *was* theirs) was necessarily unjustified.

This would be a  super-local rule change (adding complexity to the codebase, and possibly confused Meta questions) that wouldn't likely do anything to deter the user's other trolling behaviour - in fact, it would probably egg them on even more.

If you encounter persistent rude behaviour, flag for moderator attention and let them sort it out. Ignore any petty downvotes that result from the behaviour - they're the cost of being active on Stack Overflow - and move on.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133469/discussion-on-answer-by-pekka--users-who-get-flagged-for-insulting-abusive-comm).

Answer (score 9):

> It was the end of the work day and I intended to pick it up the next day.

Then simply don't post a question.

Do **not** post "hit-and-run" questions. Monitor your question for at least a couple of minutes after asking it, or you risk seeing your question closed or worse when you return.

See also [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> **Post the question and respond to feedback**
>
> After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!